# Undefined reference in make

Tags: c++, compilation, undefined-reference, matlab-engine

I'm compiling a code with many files and some are located in the local MATLAB installation folder. For this I've added an include to g++ which apparently doesn't resolve well because I get an *undefined reference to* for all MATLAB-C++ functions (I'm trying to use the MATLAB C++ Engine) as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]
The Makefile is very short and as such:

[image]

I've checked the referenced directory and it does include the "Engine.h" referenced by *constraints.cpp* which is generally enough to execute the MATLAB-C++ engine functions.

**Any ideas as to where this problem could come from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link with the MATLIB library files.  Your code is referencing them, but the linker doesn't know what they are.

Comment: mmm, excuse my ignorance, linking refers to the "-L ****" syntax (which I though meant library) or something like "-leng" "-lmx"? I used to have those in a priori version of the Makefile I used on my computer but at some point i was told by the compiler that it was not using them or something like that.

Comment: @AlexisRustamDevitre You need a -L with the path to the folder that holds the MATLAB library files.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm **-L** just adds a search directory for library finding. **-I** adds a search directory for finding includes in sources. **-l** (notice the small L), followed by the library name, instructs the linkage.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm so I need the **-L** with the location (which is what I've put in the update) and the **-l** with "eng" and "mex" which are the actual library file calls? Is that it?... Just tried it and.... I think it settles it... could you just confirm my interpretation of what you said... I'd be interested to know wether it's the right idea or not.